# WinError 10060- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, spacy

I'm trying a tutorial of spaCy(NLP) and when I try to pip install the requirements(as mentioned in the spacy website), I'm getting this error. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The same error showed up while installing NLTK as well(figured spaCy would work but the same error pops up again).

I've looked at other similar questions and found out no similarities b/w the context. I'm a beginner in ML and I'm finding it tough to deal with errors at each and every step. Please help!

Here's the full error.

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1042, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 358, in connect
    self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C494D17640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C494D17640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\_util.py", line 71, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\core.py", line 778, in main
    return _main(
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\core.py", line 216, in _main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typer\main.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 36, in download_cli
    download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 70, in download
    compatibility = get_compatibility()
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 97, in get_compatibility
    r = requests.get(about.__compatibility__)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krish\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spacy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C494D17640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Comment: You should include the code you were executing and the full stack trace, not just the last line. It sounds like an issue with your network though.

Comment: I wasn't running anything really, I was just trying to go through the installation procedure as mentioned in the spaCy website. And I'll update the post for the error trace. Regarding the network issue, I searched everywhere, but was unable to find what exactly the issue is. There are no context specific issues which deals with the current error. Also, I added the error traceback. Pls do tell me what's going wrong.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, maybe the server is down or your internet connection is failing.

Comment: The internet connection is fine(I'm connected to internet and code along the youtube tutorial). How to check if the server is down though? This error's been popping up everytime I use either NLTK or spaCy.